# Validate.unobtrusive and validate jQuery libraries

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an MVC 3 application which uses the standard Model validation attributes for basic client and server validation. I however also have a form which is in the header and uses the jQuery validate plugin to perform client validation.

When I add the unobtrusive library to the project the header form which uses the validate plugin fails to run and keeps posting. When the unobtrusive library is not included the header validates fine but then the Model validation stops.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Edit**

Basically i have a login form in the header. I also have a login page that also allows login. The login page is tied to a Model but the form in the header is not, it's just html. Both forms call the same Controller/Action via jQuery .ajax.

I have lost the ability to use the .ajax method which just doesnt seem to get called since I included the unobtrusive library.

I got the code you included to work, but then I still cant post or perform an action after validation is complete.

My header form is:

```
<form id="frmHeaderLogin" action="">
<table id="LoginBox" title="Login">
    <tr>
        <td>UserName</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Username" name="Username" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" id="btnHeaderLogin" name="btnHeaderLogin" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I have a click event for the submit button which would validate the client input and then submits this to the server after creating a JSON object as the data parameter. The response from the server is also a JSON object. This form is in a layout file as it's going to be on every page.

The main login page/view has a simple form as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MainLoginForm" }))
{
<div>
    <fieldset>
       <p style="color:Red;font-size:medium">@ViewData["Message"]</p>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, "EmailId")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, "Password")  
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">         
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" id="btnMainLogin" value="Login" />
        </p>
     </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

This also has a jQuery click event which fires the .ajax method and posts a JSON object to the server as above. Both instances return a JSON object.

I suppose at this point the question could be, can I use the same model for the header login which is in a layout file which would allow me to make use of the client and server validation?

The following is an example of the submitHandler that I was using after the validation passed (using jquery.validate)

```
    $("#formname").validate( {
     // .....
         // .....
         submitHandler: function () {
            var JSONData = new Object();
            $(':text, :password', $("table[id$='LoginBox']")).each(function () {
                JSONData[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Controller/Action",
                data: "{'Login': '" + JSON.stringify(JSONData) + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var response = $.parseJSON(result);
                    alert("Header Login Success!");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.statusText + " - ReadyState:" + xhr.readyState + "\n" + "Status: " + xhr.status);
                }
            });
         }
    )};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to mix Microsoft unobtrusive validation script with custom jquery validate rules that you have written in the same page you will need to add the jquery validate rules to existing form elements. Let's take an example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Bar').rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: 'Bar is required'
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Bar)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Bar)
    </div>

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Notice how the Required attribute on the Foo field makes it required and we have defined a custom jquery validate rule for the Bar field.

And here's the result when the form is submitted and the 2 fields are left empty:

[image]

You could of course define any number of custom rules on any field.

Comment: Darin, the form I have in the header does not use a Model. It's a standard HTML form and has a click event that calls jQuery validate and then uses the submitHandler to post. Would that still work? The form in the body has the same input names but uses a Model.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I think a submitHandler might not work because Ms unobtrusive already hijacks the submit handler. Could you show your code allowing me to see the problem? Also please narrow it down to the easiest possible example.

Comment: OK, you could replace the `submitHandler` with a `submit` subscription on the form: `$('#formname').submit(function() { if ($(this).valid()) {  ... put your AJAX code here ... } return false; });`. As far as the rules are concerned you could define them as shown in my answer. Now you could get rid of the `.validate` call.

Comment: Hi Darin, that fixed it. I had to also use e.preventDefault() to prevent the default post from occuring. Client and server validation now works.